# Cocos2D: Multiple actions: CCMoveTo CCAnimate

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccaction

I don´t understand, I absolutely cannot get this to work, I want a sequence of actions that plays an animation and moves the sprite using the `CCAnimate` ans `CCMoveTo` classes. Is there a bug or something special about these classes, cause it will not move nor animate when stringing it together in a CCSequence of actions like this.

```
    action = [CCSequence actions:
                              [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:moveDuration position:touchLocation],
                              [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:self.walkingAnim],
                              [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(objectMoveEnded)], nil];
 [self runAction:action];
```

I

Comment: any update on solving your problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the move and animate action to run paralel you can use:

**Option1**:  use CCSpawn instead of a CCSequence. CCSequence is needed because you would like to call a function after completion.

```
id action = [CCSpawn actions:
                              [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:moveDuration position:touchLocation],
                              [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:self.walkingAnim], 
                               nil];

id seq = [CCSequence actions:
                              action,
                              [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(objectMoveEnded)], 
                               nil];

[self runAction:seq];
```

**Option2**: just add any action multiple times and will be run in paralel. Because of the func-call a CCSequence again needed:

```
id action = [CCSequence actions:
                              [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:moveDuration position:touchLocation],
                              [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(objectMoveEnded)], 
                               nil];
[self runAction:action];
[self runAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:self.walkingAnim]];
```

Answer (score 1):

What this sequence does is:

- move self to the destination
- once arrived at destination, play the walking animation
- when the walk animation is finished, run the selector

I bet you meant to run the move and animate actions separately and at the same time (each with their own call to runAction) and not within a sequence.